# js-cookie, add class if different cookie is set

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cookies

I'm trying to find the way how I can add class to div if cookie with some ID is set. Using https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie. Cookie is set when we click on Button with "bar-info" class. But I don't know how to read cookie (Cookies.get) and when document is ready add class (hidden) to div with ID which is the same ID as we have set to cookie. Can someone help me?

```js
$('[different-id-bar]').each(function () {
  var $bar = $(this);
  var button = $bar.find('[data-dismiss="bar-info"]');
  //var getCookieIdName = $(document).data('cookie-id');
  var getCookieId = $(this).attr('data-cookie-id');
  var cookieName = 'data-cookie-bar-' + $(this).attr('data-cookie-id');
  //var $cookie = Cookies.get(cookieName, getCookieId);

  //if ($cookie) {
  //$bar.addClass('hidden');
  //}

  button.on('click', function () {
    Cookies.set(cookieName, getCookieId, {expires: 300});
    $bar.addClass('hidden');
  });

  //$(document).ready(function(){
    //if (Cookies.get(cookieName, getCookieId)) {
      //$bar.addClass('hidden');
    //}
  //});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js-cookie-plugin-local-destination"></script>
<div class="row row-main" data-cookie-id="2585646" different-id-bar>
 <div class="message-info">
  <p class="content">
   <a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</a>
  </p>
  <a href="#" class="btn-close" data-dismiss="bar-info"><span>Close</span></a>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use DOM relationship to get the desired data. Here [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) can be used to traverse up to `different-id-bar` element.

```
//iterate each element and read cookie
$('[data-dismiss="bar-info"]').each(function(){
    //Travese up to parent element
    var $bar = $(this).closest('[different-id-bar]');
    //Get the cookie id
    var getCookieId = $bar.attr('data-cookie-id');

    //Create cookie name
    var cookieName = 'data-cookie-bar-' + getCookieId;

    //Read cookie
    var cookie = Cookies.get(cookieName);

    //if cookie is defined and has value add css class
    if(cookie !== undefined && cookie === getCookieId){
        $bar.addClass('hidden');
    }
});


//Bind the click handler
$('[data-dismiss="bar-info"]').on('click', function(){
    //Travese up to parent element
    var $bar = $(this).closest('[different-id-bar]');
    //Get the cookie id
    var getCookieId = $bar.attr('data-cookie-id');

    //Create cookie name
    var cookieName = 'data-cookie-bar-' + getCookieId;

    $bar.addClass('hidden');

    Cookies.set(cookieName, getCookieId, {expires: 300});
});
```